# KeyError Issue using GradientExplainer shap on Tensorflow multiple input and multiple output model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, shap

I keep getting a KeyError issue with the code below.  I want to be able to explain a model with normal tabular features and a categorical feature that is turned into an embedding.

I tried to input the data into the Explainer as both dataframes and arrays using .values as shown in the code below.

```
import shap
import tensorflow as tf
##tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior() # <-- HERE !

from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, Input, Flatten, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



X_train_num = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 33)))

X_train_emb = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,19,size=(1000, 1)))

y_train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 5)))

final_features = X_train_num.columns
targets = y_train.columns

optimizer = Adam(
    learning_rate=0.0002,
#         learning_rate=0.001,

    beta_1=0.9,
    beta_2=0.999,
    epsilon=1e-07,
    amsgrad=False)
    

def get_model(final_features, targets):   
    
    no_of_unique_cat  = 20 

    embedding_size = 10


    layer_numerical = Input(shape=(len(final_features) ,)) 

    cat_input  = Input(shape=(1,))
    embed_layer = Embedding(input_dim=no_of_unique_cat, output_dim=embedding_size,)(cat_input)

    embed_layer = Flatten()(embed_layer)
    merged_layer = concatenate([layer_numerical, embed_layer])

    output = Dropout(0.1)(merged_layer)
    output = Dense(360, kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform() , activation='relu')(output)
    output = Dropout(0.3)(output)
    output = Dense(20, kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(), activation='relu')(output)
    output = Dense(len(targets))(output)
    model = models.Model(inputs=[layer_numerical,cat_input] , outputs=output)
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=optimizer)

    return model

model= get_model(final_features, targets)

history = model.fit([X_train_num, X_train_emb] , y_train, verbose=1, 
                        epochs = 10, batch_size = 50)

explainer = shap.GradientExplainer(model, [X_train_num, X_train_emb])
shap_values = explainer([X_train_num.values,X_train_emb.values])
```

Comment: I suggest you be more careful about SHAP and turn your input into 2D array

Comment: Using '.values' turns them into 2D numpy arrays. Are you referring to something different?

Comment: This one `[layer_numerical,cat_input]`. Turn into a 2D array.

Comment: These are tensors size (None, 33) and (None, 1) respectively.